# Runner is paused and will not receive any new jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently install the gitlab-ruuner in a machine and register a specific runner manually with a registration token which obtained from CI/CD Setting/runner page for my repository by :

```
 sudo gitlab-runner register
```

I start it by :

```
sudo -s gitlab-runner start
```

and output :

```
Runtime platform      arch=amd64 os=linux pid=14558 revision=f100a208 version=11.6.0
```

The CI pipeline stuck in pending mode and requires a active runner assigned to it. How can I activate the runner?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for devops.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. First I forgot to do `sudo gitlab-runner run` and after that I changed the `config.toml`. Specifically I turned privilege mode to `true`. And finally in the runner edit page, turn on the `run untagged jobs` option

Answer (score 1):

If your CI/CD job is pending, saying `This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners that can run this job. Go to Runners page.`, try restarting your gitlab runner:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner stop
$ sudo gitlab-runner start
```

If it is still not working, then try checking, if not yet, `Run untagged jobs` as below for your CI/CD runner, which by default is unchecked.

[image]